# Error in attribute when load information in informix

Tags: database, insert, load, informix

i try to load information from file in informix database, but i have some problems because some of the attributes are date , but informix is reading this as varchar

table

```
create table    temp_table(
num_evalsustento    serial  ,
num_sustento    integer ,
cod_detallereparo   integer ,
cod_confreparo  char(2) ,
cod_usuregis    varchar(30) ,
fec_regis   datetime year to second ,
cod_usumodif    varchar(30) ,
fec_modif   datetime year to second )
```

load in informix

```
LOAD FROM 'C:\Prueba\table.unl'  
INSERT INTO temp_table 
(num_evalsustento,num_sustento,cod_detallereparo,cod_confreparo,cod_usuregis
,fec_regis,cod_usumodif, fec_modif )
```

i tried to use that but didn't work

```
LOAD FROM 'C:\Prueba\table.unl'  
INSERT INTO temp_table 
(num_evalsustento,num_sustento,cod_detallereparo,cod_confreparo,
cod_usuregis, TO_DATE(fec_regis,'%d/%m/%Y'),
cod_usumodif, TO_DATE(fec_modif,'%d/%m/%Y'));
```

someone can help me ?

Comment: I suspect your unload file has something like "01/12/2020" as the datetime column. If so, try setting 'GL_DATETIME=%d/%m/%Y' and 'USE_DTENV=1' env variables before doing the "load from 'C:\Prueba\table.unl' insert into temp_table ". More info here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.glsug.doc/ids_gug_085.htm

Comment: thanks for your answer ,
do you know how can i modify environment variables? 
because I have  tried to find some information about how can do that, but i only find definitions about the topic

Comment: You are on Windows. Just do "set GL_DATETIME=%d/%m/%Y" and "set USE_DTENV=1" before you run dbaccess.exe.  Environment variables can be created using the control panel applet (Open Control Panel. Open User Accounts applet. On the left-hand side of that applet you will see a link that says Change my environment variables)